# Insert Into Transformations and Validating Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to check for combinations of values in the Insert. If none exist then I need to default to None. And only get the first 6 characters. How do I format the syntax for that? Sql Server 2008r

Psuedocode

```
Insert Into Changes
Release Information

Select
length(6, release info)
If Employer or EMPLYR, use EMPLYR
If Family, use OFAM
If FATHER use FATHER
If Friend, use OTHER
If Guardian or GUARDN, use GUARDN
If MOTHER, use MOTHER
If NONE, use NONE
If OFAM use OFAM
If OTHER, use OTHER
If PARENT OR Parents, use PARENT
If RESTR, use RESTR
If Sister, use OFAM
If Spouse, use Spouse
Else If not Valid (none of the above), use None
If Null use NROF

From Contacts
```

Comment: You should look into the CASE expression. And then look at LEFT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps all you need here is a lengthy `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN LEFT([release info], 6) IN ('Employer', 'EMPLYR') THEN 'EMPLYR'
         WHEN LEFT([release info], 6) IN ('Family', 'Sister', 'OFAM') THEN 'OFAM'
         WHEN LEFT([release info], 6) = 'FATHER' THEN 'FATHER'
         WHEN LEFT([release info], 6) IN ('Friend', 'OTHER') THEN 'OTHER'
         WHEN LEFT([release info], 6) IN ('Guardian', 'GUARDN') THEN 'GUARDN'
         WHEN LEFT([release info], 6) = 'MOTHER' THEN 'MOTHER'
         WHEN LEFT([release info], 6) IN ('PARENT', 'Parents') THEN 'PARENT'
         WHEN LEFT([release info], 6) = 'RESTR' THEN 'RESTR'
         WHEN LEFT([release info], 6) = 'Spouse' THEN 'Spouse'
         WHEN [release info] IS NULL THEN 'NROF'
         ELSE 'NONE' END AS relationship
FROM Contacts;
```

Note: Two of the values to be mapped, `Employer` and `Guardian`, are actually more than 6 characters in length.  I don't know if this is a typo, but in any case the above logic would fail for these two cases as my `CASE` expression only captures the leftmost 6 characters.  To fix this, we can either match against the first 6 characters, or take a longer substring.

Comment: OK, but keep in mind that two of your keys to be mapped (Employer and Guardian) are actually _eight_ characters long.

Comment: I'd be inclined to use `WHEN [release info] IS NULL THEN 'NROF'` rather than `WHEN LEFT([release info], 6) IS NULL THEN 'NROF'`. Using `Left()` doesn't alter the semantics, it just maintains alignment in the source code.